# Can someone explain to me the life cycle of data in a class

Tags: c#, oop

like for example the observer pattern. in the tutorial, classes(observer) registered their own to a class(observer) and then the observer class saved the observer to a list. my question is when does the observer class reset its values.

for example.

Class1.cs has a code like this,

```
//declares a property
public List<string> list;

//and then initialize it on a constructor
public class1()
{
 list = new list<string>();
}
```

and then class1 was initialized only ones.

therefore the data inside class1 will reset only when the application is closed or restarted write?

so here is another question. what if class1 was initialized more than ones.

```
class1 instance1 = new class1();

instance1.list.add("one");

class2 instance2 = new class1();
```

Comment: The concept of "resetting" is simply not one that exists in the language. When does an instance of a class "reset" its "values"? Never; there is no such thing as "resetting a value". Clarify your question to ask about something that actually exists.

Comment: @eric lippert.. in my question above, i am asking when does the class "reset its values" i don't know if there is a reset or what. what i am concern is about the life cycle of data.. and it's in my title i guess. may be my question is not clear.. sorry bout that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are confused with observers and observables.

IMO, since *events* exist in C#, there is no need to use observers and observables. But if you really want to use them, it's fine.

An **observable** is a class that will raise an event at some point. And an **observer** is something that *listens for* or *handles* the event.

Let's make this clearer by using an example. `Button` is an observable. The class can raise a `Clicked` event whenever the button is clicked. Now you wants to know *when* the button is clicked. So you subscribe to the `Button`'s click event, with an event handler method.

And you are asking when does the observable lose, or reset, the list of observers. My answer is: **it *can* do that at any time**.

As you may know, the observable keeps a list of observers as a private field. So inside the observable, the code has access to the field. So if a method or something in the observable class calls:

```
observers.Clear();
```

Then the list resets!

But what if there is no calls to the `Clear` method? When will the observers be gone?

Because the list of observers is a field, it will be discarded when the app finishes running, or some destructor destroys the instance, or it is garbage collected...

It's simple! But why are you concerned with this in the first place?

EDIT:

> therefore the data inside class1 will reset only when the application is closed or restarted write?

Yes! The data will also reset if the instance will be garbage collected.

> what if class1 was initialized more than ones

To answer this question, you need to know the difference between a *class* and an *instance*. A class is like an blueprint of a instance. When you instantiate a class, a new instance is created. So in your code, there are 2 instances of `class1`: `instance1` and `instance2`. They are completely independent, which means the `list` of `instance2` does not contain `"one"`. And when `instance1` is garbage collected, you only lose the data of `instance1`, not `instance2`. But when the application exits, all of the instances are collected and thus, the data is gone.<sup>*</sup>

<sup>*</sup><sub>Note: actually when the app closes, the instances might be still in memory. I say the data is gone because they are inaccessible.</sub>

Comment: Hi, thank you for giving time to my question. i updated my post. and added more questions

Comment: I gotta go out for a few hours, I'll update it once I come back @googleler